# create a iterate object with a group of tree from a iterate object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I create iterate group of three from a iterate object? For creating a pair of iteration function I can do something like
    from itertools import tee

```
def func(iterate):
    i, j = tee(iterate)
    next(j, None)
    return zip(i, j)

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for a, b in func(l):
    print(a, b)
> 1, 2
> 2, 3
> 3, 4
> 4, 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand on what you already did for groups of two, but with one more variable for the third item:

```
def func(iterate):
    i, j, k = tee(iterate, 3)
    next(j, None)
    next(k, None)
    next(k, None)
    return zip(i, j, k)

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for a, b, c in func(l):
    print(a, b, c)
```

This outputs:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

Note that your sample code in the question is incorrect as it is missing a call to `zip` in the returning value from `func`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

for a, b, c in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]):
    print(a, b, c)

# 1 2 3
# 2 3 4
# 3 4 5
```

You can also create groups of two with this method:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print(a, b)

# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
```